# MS Teams submitTask fails to submit to bot in IOS Teams app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I open a web/html dialog from an adaptive card with the `task/fetch Action.Submit`.
Once the user is done with the work in the web dialog, I call  `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask` with a resulting javascript object.
This works perfectly fine in the web and the desktop client. The dialog is closed and the bot on the server is triggered with the resulting object.

However in the IOS app, only the dialog is closed but the bot is never notified.
I have tried all variations of the `submitTask` (with `botId` or `appId` as second parameter or without second parameter). Nothing is successful on the IOS app.

Is there anything I can do to further debug that behaviour? Or is this a known bug?

Comment: Could you please provide us running manifest for this issue?

Comment: I just have the semi private manifest. I don't want to paste it on stackoverflow. Do you have a direct way to reach you?

Comment: Yes, you can reach us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com